# ERRO MYSQLI BD MIGRAÇÃO

Tags: php, mysql

AMIGOS , migrei de vps e após isso comecei a ter problemas com a conexão do bd `mysql`, fiz alguns ajustes mais agora não consigo achar o erro , poderiam me ajudar por favor , tenho um arquivo php que conecta ao banco e outro que envia as info segue .

o erro é :

> Host information: Localhost via UNIX socket # Warning: mysqli_query()
>   expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   /home/factor/public_html/formulario/app/model.php on line 120
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   /home/factor/public_html/formulario/app/model.php on line 121

--php conecta ao bd--

```
    <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");

/* check connection */ 
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

printf("Host information: %s\n", mysqli_get_host_info($link));

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

---php leitura de dados ----

```
function select_empresa()
{
    $sql = "SELECT e.id,e.nome_fantasia 
                FROM empresas e
                LEFT JOIN empresas_acesso ea ON(ea.id_empresa = e.id)
                WHERE ea.status = 1 AND DATE(now()) <= ea.data_expira ORDER BY nome_fantasia ASC";
    if(self::myysqli($sql))
    {
        return $this->resultt(self::myysql($sql));
    }
}

function check_acesso($empresa,$senha)
{
    if($empresa)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT e.id
                    FROM empresas e
                    LEFT JOIN empresas_acesso ea ON(ea.id_empresa = e.id)
                    WHERE ea.status = 1
                    AND e.nome_fantasia = '{$empresa}'";
        if(self::myysql($sql))
        {
            $data = $this->resultt(self::myysql($sql));
            $id = $data[0]->id;

            $senha = stripslashes(trim(str_replace(" ","",$senha)));
            $sql = "SELECT e.nome_fantasia,ea.senha
                        FROM empresas_acesso ea
                        JOIN empresas e ON(e.id = {$id})
                        WHERE ea.id_empresa = {$id}";
            if(self::myysql($sql))
            {
                $data = $this->resultt(self::myysql($sql));
                if($data[0]->senha != $senha)
                    return 501;
                else{
                    session_start();
                    session_destroy();

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['SS_empresa_id'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['SS_empresa'] = $this->reg_caracter($data[0]->nome_fantasia);
                    $_SESSION['SS_start'] = strtotime('+7200 second'); // 2 horas expira sessao
                    header("Location:".SITE_URL."/formulario/entrada");
                    die();
                }   
            }else
                return 500; // empresa desabilitada no sistema
        }
    }
}

function get_dados_formulario()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        $set_values = $set_fields = $sep = null;
        $set_v_descritores_chaves = $set_f_descritores_chaves = null;
        $set_v_pares_adjetivos = $set_f_pares_adjetivos = null;
        foreach($_POST['data'] AS $k=>$v)
        {
            if(!empty($v))
            {
                $pattern = '/^descritores_chaves/';
                $pattern2 = '/^pares_adjetivos/';
                $pattern_data = '/^data_nascimento/';
                if(preg_match($pattern_data, $k, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
                {
                    $v = $this->edit_datatime($v);
                }
                if(preg_match($pattern, $k, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
                {
                    $set_v_descritores_chaves = ',"'. self::enter_eval($v) .'"';
                    $set_f_descritores_chaves = ',descritores_chaves';
                }elseif(preg_match($pattern2, $k, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
                    $set_v_pares_adjetivos = ',"'. self::enter_eval($v,1).'"';
                    $set_f_pares_adjetivos = ',pares_adjetivos';
                }else{
                    $v = filter_var($v, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $set_fields .= $sep.$k;
                    $set_values .= $sep.'"'.$v.'"';
                    if(empty($sep)){$sep=',';}
                }
            }
        }

        $set_fields .= $set_f_descritores_chaves;
        $set_values .= $set_v_descritores_chaves;

        $set_fields .= $set_f_pares_adjetivos;
        $set_values .= $set_v_pares_adjetivos;


        $sql = "INSERT INTO cadastros ({$set_fields},data_entrada) VALUES({$set_values},now())";

        //print_r($sql);
        //exit;

        if(self::myysql($sql))
        {
            die('cadastro realizado com sucesso');
        }

    }
}

private static function myysqli($sql)
{
    if($sql)
    {
        mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");   
        return mysqli_query($sql);
    }
}

private function resultt($sql)
{
    if($sql)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

private static function enter_eval($array,$fk)
{
    $array_data = $sep = null;
    if($array)
    {
        foreach($array AS $k=>$v)
        {
            if(!empty($fk))$v = (empty($v))?100:$v;
            $v = filter_var($v, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $array_data .= $sep."'".($k)."'=>'".$v."'"; 
            if(empty($sep)){$sep=',';}
        }
        return $array_data;
    }
}

private function edit_datatime($value)
{
    if($value)
    {
        $value = explode('/',$value);
        $value = $value[2].'-'.$value[1].'-'.$value[0];
        return $value;
    }
}

private function reg_caracter($string){ 
    $a = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕ,./*'; 
    $b = 'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr    '; 
    $string = utf8_decode($string);     
    $string = strtr($string, utf8_decode($a), $b); 
    $string = strtolower($string); 
    return filter_var(stripslashes(trim(preg_replace('/\s+/','',strtolower($string)))),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde meu caro!

O erro é claro, a função **mysqli_query()** requer 2 parâmetros. Um deles é a conexão, o outro é a query que deseja executar. Exemplo:

> $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
>
> $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
>
> $result = mysql_query( $link, $sql );

Um erro que vi no seu arquivo também é que no seu arquivo de conexão você fecha a conexão com o banco sem ao menos utiliza-lá. Remova a parte do **mysqli_close()** só use após terminar de executar a **query**, lembrando que toda vez que tiver que pegar informação do banco terá que restabelecer a conexão com o banco para a consulta.

Caso não funcione, comente por favor.